# How do I use .Net Core Dependency Injection from within a custom Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Bit of a newbie question. I am having trouble getting access to dependency injected services from within my own custom class in ASP.NET Core 3.1

I can access services fine from within a controller or razor page e.g. I can get hold of configuration and data context information:

```
public class DetailModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDataContext  _context;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public DetailModel(MyDataContext context, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _context = context;
        _config = config;   
    }

etc......

 }
```

I now wish to access these from the constructor of a custom class that is not a controller or razor page. e.g. I am using:

```
public class ErrorHandling
{
    private readonly MyDataContext  _context;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;


    public ErrorHandling(MyDataContext context, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _context = context;
        _config = config;   

    }
 }
```

The problem is that when I instantiate my class it insists on me passing the service values into the constructor:

```
var myErrorHandler =  new ErrorHandling(`<wants me to pass context and config values here>`)
```

This defeats the whole point of DI. I think I am missing something fundamental here!

What am I missing?

Comment: Register `ErrorHandling` with the service collection and resolve it from the built provider. that will inject the desired dependencies

Comment: Where is it that you are trying to initialize the handler?

Answer (score 5):

You can register `ErrorHandling` as a service too, in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other stuff..
    services.AddScoped<ErrorHandling>(); // this should work as long as both 'MyDataContext' and 'IConfiguration' are also registered
}
```

If you need an instance of `ErrorHandling` in your page model, you can specify it in the constructor and ASP.NET Core will resolve it for you at runtime.

This way you won't have to `new` it:

```
public class DetailModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDataContext  _context;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ErrorHandling _errorHandling;

    public DetailModel(ErrorHandling errorHandling, MyDataContext context, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _context = context;
        _config = config;   
        _errorHandling = errorHandling;
    }

 }
```

This article can be useful: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks that works treat! The only problem is that the data context that I get from the error handling appears to reference the same context as used elsewhere in the page and doing SaveChanges() comits both which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Maybe the data context is registered as a Singleton (in Startup.cs)?

Comment: Thanks. It was registered as scoped, but changing it to transient fixed the issue. But I guess that might have performance issues elsewhere in the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want register as a service, you can use [ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-activatorutilities-createinstance(system-iserviceprovider-system-type-system-object())) to resolve ErrorHandling.

> Instantiate a type with constructor arguments provided directly and/or from an IServiceProvider.

e.g.:

```
// IServiceProvider serviceProvider = ...;
var errorHandling = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ErrorHandling>(serviceProvider);
```

**BUT** you need to be careful about this solution:

1. ServiceProvider scope should equal with dependency object (*MyDataContext*, *IConfiguration*). Otherwise, you will get an exception like:

   ```
   var errorHandling = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ErrorHandling>(app.ApplicationServices);
   // An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred 
   // in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll but was not handled in user cod
   // e: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'three.MyDataContext' from root provider.'
   ```

   For this, you can create an scope to resolve ErrorHandling:

   ```
   using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
   {
       var errorHandling = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ErrorHandling>(scope.ServiceProvider);
   }
   ```
2. Dependency injection service would not call Dispose on IDisposable instances even out of scope.

   For this, you should call Dispose() by yourself:

   ```
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
    {
        using var disposablClass = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DisposablClass>(scope.ServiceProvider);
    }
   ```
3. ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance will new an instance even you use the same ServiceProvider:

   ```
   using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
   {
       var errorHandling1 = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ErrorHandling>(scope.ServiceProvider);
       Console.WriteLine(errorHandling1.GetHashCode());
       // 11903911

       var errorHandling2 = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ErrorHandling>(scope.ServiceProvider);
       Console.WriteLine(errorHandling2.GetHashCode());
       // 40026340
   }
   ```

Comment: And why is calling `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` bettern than `new(...)`? Particularly since the question is about how to use dependency injection, not how to create the instance.